# sass map-get fails to get value of variable declared in a different file

Tags: laravel, webpack, sass

I have a `_config.scss` file in which I have defined all variables, including values for colours as follows:

```
$colors     :(  black   : black,
                1       : #161616,
                2       : #2b2b2b,
                3       : #404040,
                4       : #555555,
                5       : #6a6a6a,
                6       : #7F7F7F,
                7       : #949494,
                8       : #bebebe,
                9       : #e1e1e1,
                10      : #f2f2f2,
                11      : #fafafa,
                white   : white,
                primary : #007AFF,
                info    : #5AC8FA,
                success : #4CD964,
                warning : #FF9500,
                danger  : #FF3B30) !default;
```

I import this file in my `app.scss` file via `@import 'config'`, both these files are under the same folder. Then in a different file which is also included in the app.scss file I wish to use the colours variable

```
//////////// Colors ////////////
.background-black-30{
    background-color: rgba(map-get($colors, black), 0.3);
}
```

At all calls for map-get in the source code I get the same error while compiling assets

```
ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

    background-color: rgba(map-get($colors, black), 0.3);
                     ^
      $color: null is not a color.
    background-color: rgba(map-get($colors, black), 0.3);
```

***update***

So this is interesting, the error is for line 19 on _bootstrap.scs

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

        color: darken(map-get($colors, 'primary'), 10%);
              ^
      $color: null is not a color.
        color: darken(map-get($colors, 'primary'), 10%);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  resources/sass/components/_bootstrap.scss 19:16  @import
  resources/sass/_components.scss 1:9              @import
  stdin 20:9                                       root stylesheet
```

in that file, I'm using keys before line 19 also but that seems to compile without errors

```
/////////////////////////////////////////
// Global general styles
/////////////////////////////////////////
body{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

* {outline: none !important;}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

a{
    color: map-get($colors, 'primary');
    transition: $transition;
    &:hover, &:focus{
        color: darken(map-get($colors, 'primary'), 10%); 
        text-decoration-color: currentColor;
    }
}
```

so the line `color: map-get($colors, 'primary');` doesn't throw an error, but `color: darken(map-get($colors, 'primary'), 10%);` does.

Comment: Try to quote your keys ? `$colors:(  'black'   : black)`

From the sass doc: "Most of the time, it’s a good idea to use quoted strings rather than unquoted strings for map keys. This is because some values, such as color names, may look like unquoted strings but actually be other types. To avoid confusing problems down the line, just use quotes!"

Comment: did that, I still get the same error. I've changed all the keys including numbers.